# lost access to azure devops organization and azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

i changed my office365 account subscription from Godaddy to Office365 from Microsoft Store.
Now i lost my access to my previous devops organization, azure portal, and teams channel.

The step i switch my account is:

1. Unsubscribe my Office 365 in Godaddy
2. Remove my DNS record from my domain in Godaddy.
3. Sign up  with same account & domain to Office 365 in Microsoft Store and add required DNS record to my new hosting provider.
4. Then i can login to my Office 365 account but lost all access i mention above. Additionally my mailbox is now empty too.

How to restore my access? Because now my client also cannot invite me as a project contributor to their Devops organization too which my account has been invited before i migrate my account.

Comment: Have you performed IMAP migration to move the mailbox data? Also, have you verified your domain in Office 365? 

IMAP Migration : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/Exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/migrating-imap-mailboxes?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fWhat-you-need-to-know-about-migrating-your-IMAP-mailboxes-to-Office-365-3fe19996-29bc-4879-aab9-5a622b2f1481

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/Exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/migrating-imap-mailboxes?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fWhat-you-need-to-know-about-migrating-your-IMAP-mailboxes-to-Office-365-3fe19996-29bc-4879-aab9-5a622b2f1481

Comment: i only change the Office365 tenant, do i need to perform IMAP Migration?
Yes i verified my domain in Office 365

Comment: Yes, the migration is required. Please see a similar thread here that might help you: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/moving-godaddy-office365-to-microsoft-office365/53e7ce07-955f-4840-997d-0f427cdbb6a7

Comment: the problem here is i already cancel my godaddy office 365 account, so i don't have access to my old account now. What should i do?

Comment: Actually the main problem is not on the mailbox, but my main problem is on the Azure Devops, Azure Portal, and Ms Teams. 

Because my account is invited as a team member on my client's devops, portal, and teams. Now i can't access them anymore even my client has reinvite me. It seems like there is a problem on the Azure AD, but i'm not sure and i don't know what to do.

Comment: are you able to access the Azure DevOps now? If not, maybe deleting and re-inviting could help. If you still have issues, you can post your question to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html